# Detecting Key Presses

Tags: vb.net, keypress

I am writing a program that expands the usage of the clipboard, but I need to tell when the user has either cut, copied, or pasted something so I can write code accordingly to that. I need to know how I can check to see when the user has entered a command like this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with trapping keystrokes is what if someone clicks the "Copy" button on the toolbar, or goes to Edit > Copy on the menu?

What you probably need to do is trap an event emitted by the Clipboard itself for whenever it changes.  Glancing at Google it seems there isn't a .NET api yet, but there is still an old Win32 one... [Create a Windows Clipboard Monitor in VB](http://jo0ls-dotnet-stuff.blogspot.com/2008/12/setclipboardviewer-api-vbnet.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if detecting keys is the best way to do that.

Anyway, you can find out if the clipboard contents changed by monitoring it.
Check out this article: [How to monitor the clipboard in Visual Basic](http://www.rolbe.com/2009/03/11/how-to-monitor-the-clipboard-in-visual-basic/)